# Add attribute in Bannercomponents Admin tab [cmscockpit] Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have added one custom attribute in SimpleCMSComponent which I am able to see in backoffice but not in CMS cockpit.
Is there any file do I need to update to show this field in CMSCockpit ?
to be more precise I am trying to show this field in BannerComponent's Admin or Basic tab.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Jemie

Please have a look.
https://answers.sap.com/questions/12759977/how-to-show-new-attributes-on-contentpage-in-cms-c.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes need to be added in EditorArea_BannerComponent.xml and then system update is required by selecting OOTB cockpits and custom cockpit extensions.